# PayPal - Native Checkout SDK(iOS)- Invalid scope

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am following Native Checkout SDK   https://developer.paypal.com/limited-release/native-checkout/ios/ and using the code same as documentation

**Configuartion Client id and return url given**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        let config = CheckoutConfig(
                clientID: "XXX",
                returnUrl: "xyz",
                environment: .sandbox
            )
            Checkout.set(config: config)
        return true
    }
```

```
    func configurePayPalCheckout() {
           print("__________________________________________________________________________________________________")
           Checkout.setCreateOrderCallback { createOrderAction in
               let amount = PurchaseUnit.Amount(currencyCode: .usd, value: "10.00")
               let purchaseUnit = PurchaseUnit(amount: amount)
               let order = OrderRequest(intent: .capture, purchaseUnits: [purchaseUnit])

               createOrderAction.create(order: order)
           }

           Checkout.setOnApproveCallback { approval in
                approval.actions.capture { (response, error) in
                   print("Order successfully captured: \(response?.data)")
                    print("error ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::",error)
               }
           }
            Checkout.setOnCancelCallback {
                // User has cancelled the payment experience
                print("cancel")
            }
            Checkout.setOnErrorCallback { error in
                // Handle the error generated by the SDK
                print("error" , error)
            }
    }
```

When i click on paypal button it gives me the below error

> Sorry about that
> Looks like this action is not supported. Please return and report this error so that we can support it in the future. (invalid scope)

[Sorry about that
Looks like this action is not supported. Please return and report this error so that we can support it in the future. (invalid scope)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dahUb.png)

If anyone have faced this issue kindly do help
Thanks

Comment: any one got the solution?

Comment: do set the scope items from Paypal dashboard console.